# Suddenly Error CakePHP on AWS Server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, cakephp, caching

I have an instance on Amazon Web Service. My Website App is using cakephp. Previously, the website is running normally, but suddenly there are so much errors with detail below:

> write failed: No space left on device
>
> unserialize(): Error at offset 4069 of 4085 bytes
>
> _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_id' to File cache
>
> _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'default_en-us' to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 323] (many more)

I am sure that my file `/app/tmp` is writeable (777) include all of my file and directory.
Why this is happen? what exactly causes the error? please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks your HDD is full.

```
write failed: No space left on device
```

The error says there is no space left on your disk.

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: Delete a few files from your server? Or attach a larger disk to it.

Comment: so how about the error : _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_id' to File cache

Comment: Its related to the same problem? You are unable to write file because your disk if full. Free up some space and restart your server.

Comment: how to delete or get more space in amazon? or anything you know maybe can help me

Comment: Are you able to login to the server via ssh? Check the guide here -> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstances.html

Comment: yes i have know how to connect the server using putty. but untill now i did not get advice to solve my problem. this is really urgent matter :((

Comment: Log in to your server -> Find large un-needed files taking up space and delete them. Restart your server and see if your problem is solved.

Comment: You can always try to cleanup /tmp first.  But most likely you're just allowing monster logs to grow and eat up all the space.

Comment: previously i have try to send email to all user in database, is that caused the error?